# How to validate cloned inputs using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clone, identity

I have a problem using the identity element.
Basically, I want to create a simple html form where the user can input a phone number - related to a certain code - that needs to be validated and sent to a certain folder.

However I want to give the users the possibility to input as many phone numbers as they want. So it seemed logical for me to use the clone method. However, the negative aspect of using this method is that the identity is always the same. In other words, if a phone number has an incorrect input, I cannot refer the user to the input text that is not corresponding with the validation rules.

I already tried several things, but I simply do not know how to increment the identity element 'Tel' by 1, or to validate each input text.

Below you can find my code. I used the getElementsByName method because Firefox automatically assigns an incremented number to each input name. However if I could find a way to increment the identity by 1 for each input text that is used, I would prefer this way of working. 
I'm open for every suggesting, but I prefer to use plain javascript as I'm not familiar with JQuery.

Thx in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SMS</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name;
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;


function checkPhone() {

var x=document.getElementsByName("Tel").length;


var TotTel = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
TotTel[i] += document.getElementsByName('PhoneNumber')[i].value;


if(TotTel[i] == "" || TotTel[i] == null)
{
alert("Please enter a phone number");
return false;
}

else if(isNaN(TotTel[i]))
{
    alert("You can only enter numbers");
    return false;
}
}
alert("Validation ok");
return true;
}

</script>


<div id="readroot" style="display:none">

    <input type="button" value="Remove field" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"  /><br /><br />

    Phone number:   <input name="PhoneNumber" class="Tel" id="Tel" />

    SMSCode: <select name="SMSCodes">
        <option>Codes</option>
        <option value="B2BNL"> B2BNL </option>
        <option value="B2BFR"> B2BFR </option>
        <option value="B2BEN"> B2BEN </option>
        <option value="B2CNL"> B2CNL </option>
        <option value="B2CFR"> B2CFR </option>
        <option value="B2CEN"> B2CEN </option>
        <option value="AMNL"> AMNL </option>
        <option value="AMFR"> AMFR </option>
        <option value="PMNL"> PMNL </option>
        <option value="PMFR"> PMFR </option>
        <option value="PMPNL"> PMPNL </option>
        <option value="PMPFR"> PMPFR </option>
        <option value="BWAYAM"> BWAYAM </option>
        <option value="BWAYPM"> BWAYPM </option>
        <option value="BWAYPMP"> BWAYPMP </option>
        <option value="BWAY18"> BWAY18 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSNL1114"> SPEOSNL1114 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSFR1114"> SPEOSFR1114 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSNL1417"> SPEOSNL1417 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSFR1417"> SPEOSFR1417 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSNL1721"> SPEOSNL1721 </option>
        <option value="SPEOSFR1721"> SPEOSFR1721 </option>  
    </select><br /><br />
</div>

<form name="SMSForm" action="" onsubmit="checkPhone()" method="post">

    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="More Phone numbers" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in your code, it should work if you fix it.

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("Tel").length;
```

The above expression evaluate to 0 as "Tel" is the id of textfield.

```
for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
```

Please be aware that firefox assign 1 to the first textfield, not 0.

```
TotTel[i] += document.getElementsByName('PhoneNumber')[i].value;
```

The above line of code bugs as it only return nodes of exactly the name "PhoneNumber", not "PhoneNumberSomething". You can try something like

```
TotTel[i] += document.getElementsByName('PhoneNumber'+i)[0].value;
```

As for example PhoneNumber1 is a unique name, so the method return one element array.
And please be aware that user can add a few more phone number fields, then delete the first one. The resulting number sequence will be 1, 3, 4... but PhoneNumber2 does not exist.

I though of two methods to handle this problem.

The first one is to construct an array or similar to store the node when you clone it and remove from the array when user remove it, so that you can find any cloned nodes from that array E.g.

```
arr[counter] = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
```

The second method uses jquery
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
$("form input[name*=PhoneNumber]")
```

The above selector will select all textfield with name containing PhoneNumber in the form.